# Create template that appends to existing template - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I ran into a situation in AngularJS where I want to use a template that appends to the same template when data is changed instead of replacing the existing template. Directive can be something like this:

```
<my-template data="myData"></my-template>
```

`template.html` can be like:

```
<p>ID: {{data.id}}, Name: {{data.name}}</p>
```

The data will contain single data, so when I change data I want above template to append instead of replacing it. So the output will be like this:

ID: 1, Name: John

ID: 2, Name: Michael

ID: 3, Name: Abraham

I also want to handle onClick when the user tap on any name above.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it ! try this

```
         angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope, $interval) {
        var count = 0;
        var addPerson = function() {
            count++
            $scope.person = {
                name: 'person' + count,
                age: 20 + count
            };

        };

        var timer = $interval(addPerson, 1000);
    })

     .directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
       return {
          restrict: "A",
          transclude: true,
          scope: "=",
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


            scope.handleClick = function(event) {

                console.log(event.target.innerText)

            }

            scope.$watch(function() {
                return scope.person;
            }, function(obj) {

                var elementToRender = angular.element('<div ng-click="handleClick($event)">' + obj.name + '</div>');

                function renderDiv() {


                    return elementToRender
                }

                element.append(renderDiv());
                $compile(elementToRender)(scope);
            }, false);


        }
    };
});
```

template

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> 
<div my-directive data="{{person}}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read my question again... I don't want to use `ng-repeat`, instead I just want to append data at the end of div everytime I change its value in template.

Comment: @codelearner Angular works by 2-way binding, that means your view syncs with your object model. Now you are saying you want to let them out of sync, I'm afraid you can't do that in straight forward way.

Comment: This is completely out of concept. Read my question again.